# Emission particle object gets mixed

Tags: modeling, animation, particles, parent, emission

I made a moth and made the wings seperately then parented it to the body and animated the wings using shape keys. But after I used the particle emission everything just got mixed up. Like the wings and the body got seperated..How can I fix that?

Comment: you should not parent but join all the object elements: body + wings

Comment: Then how will I animate the wings??

Comment: once you've joined the body and the wings you can use shapekeys or bones